# Make a query to select a value from one column that is combined with all the values from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine I have the following tables:

| Numbers PK |
| --- |
|  |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 10 |

| Numbers FK 1 | Numbers FK 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 8 | 8 |
| 10 | 4 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 4 | 9 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 |

I have the following tables: "Numbers PK" as Primary key and another 2 tables that are related one with each other that are foreign keys of Numbers.

I am trying to make a query to select the number(s) from the table "NumbersFK2" that are related with all the numbers of "Numbers PK".

As you can see in this example the solution would be 1 as 1 is related with 1-10 in the tables "Numbers FK1" and "Numbers FK2"

I have tried to solve and after some days I need some help as I don't know how could I do it. I appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use `dense_rank()` to count the `Numbers_PK` in case they're not consecutive. Then we `left join`, `group by` and `count(distinct Numbers_PK)`.

```
with t3 as (
           select  Numbers_PK
                  ,dense_rank() over(order by Numbers_PK) as dns_rnk
           from    t
           )
  
select   Numbers_FK_2       
from     t3 left join t2 on t2.Numbers_FK_1 = t3.Numbers_PK
group by Numbers_FK_2
having   count(distinct Numbers_PK) = max(dns_rnk)
```

| Numbers_FK_2 |
| --- |
| 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4-VdX61n)

Comment: the last line having   count(distinct Numbers_PK) = max(dns_rnk)
 is reporting "dns_rnk" column doesn't exist

Comment: @Lechius you copied something wrong (probably the alias). check out my fiddle.

Comment: it is working perfect, but what abaout if I want to exclude the 1-1 from the list? I mean, I want the query to work with 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and 1 would not be neccesary to be related with itself, how could I do that?

Comment: @Lechius please choose my answer and vote it up. here's the second thing you're looking for. pay attention to the join and the having: https://dbfiddle.uk/UQmd-5-D